# What's the best way to demonstrate differences in these means/totals?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, nonparametric, goodness-of-fit, kruskal-wallis-test

With some co-authors, I coded 200 video game reviews based on whether they mentioned any of nine different game elements. We now have the total number of times that each game element showed up in these reviews, and we’d like to run some kind of test to demonstrate that some elements showed up significantly more times than others. We’ve looked into two ways of testing this and hit obstacles with both ways:

We’d hoped to use a chi-square goodness of fit test to determine whether each element showed up an equal number of times in the data; however, the nine different game element categories aren’t mutually exclusive (i.e., one game review might have several game elements in it), which violates the assumptions of a chi-square test.

We explored using an ANOVA test (or equivalent) to determine whether the mean instances of a game element per review differed significantly for the nine different game elements. The data don't have a normal distribution, so I'm looking into a Kruskal-Wallis test, but the data also violate the assumption of homogeneity of variance; it's not clear to me whether Kruskal-Wallis can also handle this, or if there's another route we should take.